# Laravel Eloquent saving an object with children

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to save an `order` with `order_items` but I am not really finding anything in the docs to support this use case. A hasMany relationship.

Basically there is an `orders` table with something like `id | user_id` and an `order_items` table with `id | order_id | product_id`.

How can I `save()` the order and use an array of items at the same time without having to loop over the items and save them individually?

Is this possible?

Pseudo code assuming `$items` is an array:

```
$items = Session::get("cart.items");

$order = new Order;
$order->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
$order->order_items = $items;
$order->save();
```

Comment: Have you tried using `attach()`? Although in my case I had to loop through the array.

Comment: Could you provide an example? I am happy to loop if it solves this :) I am not able to make it work. Please post as an answer.

Comment: @Jason Re: "Update Here is the working code I ended up using:", is that your final code that solved your problem? If yes, it is an answer and should be moved to the answer section. Thank you.

Comment: @Pang The correct answer was by deczo and I only included my code based on their answer to help others in the future. Thank you for looking out for this stuff :)

Comment: @Jason Stackoverflow is a Q & A site. The question section is for questions only and the answer section is for answers. You should move your final code to the answer section because it is NOT part of the question, it is a solution to your question. Thanks.

Comment: @Pang This is getting long. I removed my update but I do not feel comfortable creating a new answer as there is already a correct answer. Should I edit that answer or create a new answer? I see a lot of users putting their working code in their question such as I have done.

Comment: You should never edit some other's answer. That's vandalism. You can answer your own question and it is actually encouraged (as long as it actually answers the question). See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) in the Help Center. Putting answers in the question section is wrong and should be removed, although the poor moderators can't catch them all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you need for a `hasMany` relation is either `saveMany` or `createMany`, depending on what's in your `$items` array:

```
// array of attributes:
$items = [
  ['name'=>'item1','price'=>'price1'],
  ...
];

// then createMany:
$order->orderItems()->createMany($items);
```

This will create new rows in `Item`s table.

---

```
// array of models:
$items = [
  Item::find($someId),
  Item::find($anotherId),
  // and/or newly instantiated:
  new Item(['name'=>'item1','price'=>'price1']),
  ...
];

// then createMany:
$order->orderItems()->saveMany($items);
```

This will associate (save) existing models, and create non-existing ones.

---

**Also notice that I use camelCase relation name `orderItems` instead of your `order_items`**.
This is an important detail, since Eloquent (Laravel v4) looks for camelCased methods on the model when working with relations (dynamic properties).

```
//Order model
public function orderItems()
{
  return $this->hasMany(...);
}

$order->orderItems; // collection
$order->order_items; // collection as well

// --------------------
// BUT
public function order_items()
{
  return $this->hasMany(...);
}

$order->orderItems; // null
$order->order_items; // null

// the only way you can work with relation then, is explicitly use method like:
$order->order_items()->get();
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Where did you learn about this? I am unable to find docs on this at all. I will update my question with working code. Thank you.

Comment: Brilliant. Was looking for a way to create an order model and a load of orderlines, but not save any of them until the very end. The orderlines are put into a collection, then the final save is `$order->save(); $order->orderlines()->saveMany($orderlines);`. Either an array or a collection can be used.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the best solution you are looking for, but this should work.

Let's say that the array is named `$items`, I'm under the impression that you will be saving it into a pivot table. In my example below I also have a 3rd field on `item_order` pivot table named `item_quantity`.

```
foreach ($items as $item)
{
    $order->items()
    ->attach($item['item_id'], ['item_quantity' => $item['item_quantity']]);
}
```

Basically you will be looping through the `$items` array. This will assume that you have defined the relationship on your Order model called `items()`.

Then use the `attach()` method

`->attach([insert the item_id], array('3rd field name' => 'value to be inserted')`

Finally, if you don't have a 3rd field on your pivot table you could just do

`->attach($item_id)`

You can check the example given at the Laravel [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#inserting-related-models)

**Note**

`attach()` is the method used when the you are only creating a record on the Database, otherwise you need a different method when you want to update.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this tomorrow. There are just two tables related on orders.id = order_items.order_id

Comment: `attach` is a `BelongsToMany` method and it doesn't save related model, only a row in the pivot table.

Comment: The below answer was correct. Thank you for your time though, I still learned from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

@jareks answer helped in a similar scenario except for a **mass assignment exception** . so on digging up docs i found that you need to **set a guarded or fillable property**  for mass assignment in latest versions of laravel **(4.2)** .

please refer this along with his answer .

**Fillable or guarded properties**

When creating a new model, you pass an array of attributes to the model constructor. These attributes are then assigned to the model via mass-assignment. This is convenient; however, can be a serious security concern when blindly passing user input into a model. If user input is blindly passed into a model, the user is free to modify any and all of the model's attributes. For this reason, all Eloquent models protect against mass-assignment by default.

So set the fillable or guarded properties on your model. [Docs and Source](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#mass-assignment)

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    protected $fillable = array('first_name', 'last_name', 'email');

}
```